# Data absent reason in FHIR - ExplanationOfBenefit

Tags: hl7-fhir, hl7-v2

I am new to FHIR resource implementations. I am implementing a use case where I am using BigQuery SQL to create the FHIR structure of the FHIR ExplanationOfBenefit-Outpatient-Institutional resource. Here, is the link of the structure definition I am following: https://hl7.org/fhir/us/carin-bb/STU1.1/StructureDefinition-C4BB-ExplanationOfBenefit-Outpatient-Institutional.html

Now, in the definition, there is a slice called "discharge-status" inside the field called "supportingInfo". Based on the guide, the value for this field should be one of the values associated to binding of NUBC Patient Status Codes ValueSet.

But, in my use case, I can have null values as well which does not belong to the ValueSet. How can I add data absent reason code to this field in the event I do not have data for their field?

If this query needs more explanation, I am happy to add that.
Requesting help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discharge-status.code element has a required binding.  That means the element *must* have a code from the value set if it is present in the instance.  If you have a null value, then omit the entire slice, as the slice itself is optional.